# Why does R Studio remember all my open tabs after completely uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Tags: r, rstudio

I completely uninstalled R Framework and R Studio from my Mac.

I moved the applications to trash, and also in `terminal` ran the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \
   /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript
```

I then downloaded brand new (latest versions) of R and R Studio and installed them.

When I open R Studio again after re-installing, I expect a blank, new, default environment but instead all my tabs (open R and Rmd files) are still present and open in R Studio.

How can this be??

Also, the bug I'm trying to resolve with one of my packages is still persisting

Comment: I don't use R studio, but is it possible that it creates its own bunch of folders to store preferences, history, etc? Did you check your home directory `~` for any left over files? It may be in a folder starting with `.rstudio` or similar

Answer (score 3):

I am using RStudio 0.99.489 on a Linux machine, and for me RStudio automatically saves user settings to `~/.rstudio-desktop`, for example holding:

- history: ~/.rstudio-desktop/history_database
- files pane settings: pcs/files-pane.pper

Since user settings were not deleted then of course the next time you re-installed RStudio, RStudio follows these histories, pane settings etc again.

To have a completely default appearance, be sure you quit RStudio first, then delete it like:

```
$ rm -r ~/.rstudio-desktop
```

Then start RStudio and it should appear with the default appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all environment objects, cleared the workspace, uninstalled R Framework and R Studio, and restarted my computer.  This seemed to fix the issue.

I think clearing the workspace was the key after trying a re-install several times.

`$ rm -r ~/.rstudio-desktop` as the other answer suggests is good to try as well.